# Error while saving the record in apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

my controller is like this

```
public class newaccountcontroller 
{
    public Account acct{get;set;}

    public newaccountcontroller(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) 
    {
             this.acct = (Account)stdController.getRecord();

    }

    Public pagereference NewAccount()
    {
        Insert acct;
        return null;
    }

    public pagereference cancelButton()
    {
        Pagereference cnclbutton = new Pagereference('/apex/accountdisplay');
        cnclbutton.setredirect(true);
        return cnclbutton;
    }

}
```

My VF page is like below

```
<apex:page standardController="account" extensions="newaccountcontroller">
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlockSection >
    <apex:inputField value="{!Account.name}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!Account.accountnumber}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!Account.type}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!Account.industry}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!Account.rating}"/>
    Email:<apex:inputText />
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:form>

<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!NewAccount}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!CancelButton}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>

</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

I am trying o save the object but i am getting the following error..pls help

error is

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Account
>   Name]: [Account Name] Error is in expression '{!NewAccount}' in
>   component  in page newaccount:
>   Class.newaccountcontroller.NewAccount: line 13, column 1

Comment: Somebody please help ..I am a newb to this

Comment: You can sidestep the problem for now by using `<apex:inputField value="{!Account.name}" required="true"/>` which will force all users to enter the required Account name value before the insert is done.

Comment: @keithC - Even after making the change.;.I am getting the same error..

the code was woe=rking fine below..but by mistake i removed somethign from the apex class and not its giving an errror

Comment: If you are working in eclipse you can get the old instance from the history. it is good if you can post the current error you are comming across

Comment: i am not working on Eclipse..@suri 

Error is "System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Account Name]: [Account Name]"

Comment: Bring all components under one form tag. Using more than one form increases Viewstate size whih is not a good practise

Comment: The command button sends an empty form data so that's why there are missing account's fields. Please refer to my answer.

Comment: Hey Ankita, did you try to place the input fields and command buttons under one form as I suggested?

Comment: @Ruslan Vekua - Its working Now..thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<apex:inputField...>` elements and the command buttons should be in the same `<apex:form...>` container.